# How to select the non-static elements with non-static ids?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to use selenium on Facebook but after each time I start the bot A modal opens and asks for 'Allow the use of cookies from Facebook on this browser?' I want to close the modal by clicking on "Only allow essential cookies" button but whenever I refresh the page, the ID of the button changes.

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="u_0_l_GM"]'))).click()
```

The "u_0_l_GM" part. "GM" changes on every refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy here you can use the xpath inbuilt function contains you need to change your xpath to this
//*[contains(@id,"u_0_l_")]

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to find the previous element which is static and traverse into the targeted element by using the following method in xpath

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).